# Data\Feature Leakage - feature too close to target?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, data-leakage

#### In General:

The target itself built from very correlated features, because there is no ground truth - only rule based one. 
I have a problem in the following method: 
Output: binary. built from **multiple binary scenarios**. 
Input: multiple features + **features very close to the scenario**.

#### For Example:

Output: predict whether the customer is money laundering. The target is not a ground truth (the future trial decision is not available) - 
 scenario for example: Has the number of returned checks >= 10? 
Input: multiple features + feature -  how many checks returned?

I think there is some flaw here, maybe it's not data leakage (because input is in t(n-1) and target in t(n)). 
'The flaw' - I'll recognize the target very close to the target itself (t(n-k); k is small). 
 If I will not using that feature - I'll 'close my eyes to reality'; even if the model I use is very good.

 
Does my intuition make sense? What will the downside of using those features?

Thanks.

Comment: Both of these looks like a Feature and highly correlated. I think you're setting something in between ML and Rule-based. In ML setup, your output should be Yes/No

Comment: Canyon please elaborate, what do you mean with „some flaw“?

Comment: I edited my post -
'The flaw' - I'll recognize the target very close to the target itself (at time t(n-1)).
If I will not using that feature - I'll 'close my eyes to reality'; even if the model I use is very good.